# lowercase "s" not working properly in \textgoth (yfonts, overleaf)

Tags: fonts

Basically the title: I need a lowercase gothic font "s" but `\textgoth{s}` (with the package `yfonts` on Overleaf) doesn't work properly (check the image to see the strange result I get).

Does somebody know how to solve this problem? Are there others packages I could use?

[image: result of \textgoth{so}(3)]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please always provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). What is the output you try to get? In the picture you show, I see a long s (U+017F: ſ) which is to be expected since it is the way the package works. If you want to output a final s, you need to use `\textgoth{s:}`.

Comment: Wouldn’t `\mathfrak{s}` do? With `\usepackage{amsfonts}`

Comment: As @JasperHabicht says the lowercase final s is encoded in those fonts as a `s:` logature. However, it seems to me that you are just trying to type the so(3) algebra, right? The you don't need the text fonts. `\mathfrak` is enough.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Thank you for the edit, I'm new around here and I, clearly :), don't know much about this stuff...I didn't even know what was the character I was getting!

Comment: I have to admit that the long s in these fonts looks a lot like a small l, so I can totally understand your confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ygoth` font has a “long s” at the slot for “s”. The final “s” is found at slot (hexadecimal) `"60`, where usually the back quote sits.

When writing with `ygoth`, if you want a final s, you access it by `s:`.

So you could use `\textgoth{s:o}`, but this is error prone. Here's an alternative approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{ygoth}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{ygoth}{m}{n}{<->ygoth}{}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathgothinner}{U}{ygoth}{m}{n}

% the final s sits at slot "60 in the font
\DeclareRobustCommand{\mathgoth}[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \mathcode`s="7160
  \mathgothinner{#1}%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\lie}[1]{\operatorname{\mathgoth{#1}}}

\begin{document}

The Lie algebra $\lie{so}(3)$ is interesting.

\end{document}
```

I load the `ygoth` font as a math alphabet and define `\mathgoth` as a wrapper where, inside a group, the mathcode of `s` is changed to point to the backquote slot.

Next I define a semantic wrapper for your need, namely `\lie`.

[image]

If you change your mind and decide to try AMS `\mathfrak`, you just comment out the code from `\DeclareFontFamily` to the line with `\newcommand{\lie}`, add `\usepackage{amsfonts}` and

```
\newcommand{\lie}[1]{\operatorname{\mathfrak{#1}}}
```

to get

[image]

The you can take your pick.

Comment: Curiosity: why `\mathop`?

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you want to output a final s and not a long s (U+017F: ſ). The `yfrak` package assings `s` the long s, because it is used more often than a final s that only appears at the end of words (or a the end of parts of composita such as Haustür).

The Readme file provided with the `yfrak` package (see, for example [on CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/yfonts)) explains, that you should use `s:` to access the final s.

So, in your case, you can use the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{yfonts}

\begin{document}

\textgoth{s:o}(3)

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

As suggested in the comments, if you want to use fraktur letters in math mode, it might be reasonable to use `\mathfrak` provided by the `amsfonts` or `amssymb` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}

$\mathfrak{so}(3)$

\end{document}
```

[image]